# JQuery datepicker - allow character 'M' as literal in dateFormat option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

How can I allow the character 'M' to be treated as literal in a datepicker control? I am using the following code to add a datepicker to my page:

```
    $("#txtDateTime").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'themes/Main/images/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy 00:00 AM'
    });
```

I want the textbox to show '07/21/2011 00:00 AM' when a date is selected using the datepicker but 'M' is treated as format character for month and the control displays '07/21/2011 00:00 AJuly'. How can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must escape litterals.

```
$("#txtDateTime").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'themes/Main/images/calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy 00:00 AM'
});
```